# How can I fix my conversor date Problem on BIG QUERY?

Tags: sql, datetime, google-bigquery

I'm trying to convert a YYYYMMDD and hour minute to DateTime on Big Query (each one comes separetly)
The code is:

```
`select  CONCAT( SUBSTR(date, 0 , 4), '-' ,SUBSTR(date, 5 , 2), '-' , SUBSTR(date, 7 , 2),' ', CAST( H.hour as string format '00'),':',CAST( H.minute as string format '00'),':','00' )`
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JyJi.png)

How can I delete that space?
I can't see the problem and I need to Convert that to DateTime

BY now, I try to convert that data to datetime by a few ways BUT I couln't solve it yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Bigquery, this can be done by the follow steps

1. Use [parses_date()](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#parse_date) function to get date ojbect
2. Add hour and minute as [time](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/time_functions#time) object
3. Construct the [datetime](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/datetime_functions#datetime) object

```
datetime(parse_date('%Y%M%d',date), time(H.hour, H.minute,0))
```